# Separate the variables view in eclipse

Tags: eclipse

I am using this Version of eclipse `Version: Luna Service Release 1 (4.4.1)` is there anyway in eclipse to separate the variables window when Debugging code to watch it at the other screen?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the views are separable. Just drag the tab to another location and the view will appear in its own window.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this could be an solution
http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/100946/

You could "detach" all views and arrange them on your "secondary" 
monitor. Each view will appear in a window of its own, but you can stack 
several views by dragging them into the same window.